# Linkedin external login is not working after Open Id Connect in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, linkedin-api

I have been working on Linkedin login in .net web api. it was working fine when there was not OpenId Connect.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5tFr.png)

As I am using Authorized url as "http://localhost:60418/signin-linkedin" which was working fine.

but today when I setup same thing using OpenId Cnnect it is not working. It opens a linkedin popup and when I enter correct credetainal it is not allowing me to login and giving access_denied.

Do I miss any basic settings or is there any changes in OpenID Connect?

Any help would be grate appreciated

My previous code was working but right now it is not working.

Comment: this might help: https://auth0.com/blog/authenticating-a-user-with-linkedin-in-aspnet-core/

Comment: anyway, I dont think OIDC is the protocol you are looking for, and most likely OAuth is the way to go for you. You provided pretty much zero info about your use case, also did not provide code, so not much I can do to help.